# Обязательно ли в rabbitmq нужно закрывать соединение?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

Только начал знакомиться с rabbitmq, посмотрел примеры с офф сайта

> Наконец, закрываем соединение и выходим

```
setTimeout(function() {
    connection.close();
    process.exit(0)
}, 500);
```

мой пример кода

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');

amqp.connect('amqp://localhost', function(error0, connection) {
    if (error0) {
        throw error0;
    }
connection.createChannel(function(error1, channel) {
    if (error1) {
        throw error1;
    }

    channel.assertQueue('ses', {
        durable: false
    });

    app.get('/serv1',async (req, res) => {
        const data = {
            name: 'name',
            server: '3009',
        }

        await channel.sendToQueue("ses", Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(data)))
        // res.send(data)
    })

    app.listen(3009, () => {
        console.log('server start')
    })
});
```

});

Например через Postman я отправлю request, то все удачно приходит и я получаю сообщение, но если я вставлю код выше, то при отправки повторного запроса, я получаю ошибку, я понимаю из за чего происходит эта ошибка, но я так и не могу понять зачем закрывать соединение?

В моем понимании если слушать порт

```
app.listen(3009, () => {
   console.log('server start')
})
```

то зачем его закрывать, или я что то не правильно делаю, помогите разобраться!

update

[image: ide]

Comment: 1. `я получаю ошибку` в тексте ошибки содержится, что пошло не так, и даже строчки, где она произошла. 2. соединение нужно закрывать, когда кролик больше не нужен. у вас скрипт работает в режиме демона? естественно, подключение закрывать не нужно. 3. `connection.createChannel` - канал нужно создавать только один раз. при перезапуске тут скорее всего будет ошибка 4. иногда подключение падает, например сетевой сбой. не пишите так код, он не сможет обработать ситуацию отключения от кролика. если этот код взят и урока, это неудачный урок

Comment: @TotalPusher разместите как ответ? Комментарии для ответов не предназначены ;-)

Comment: @Total Pusher я запускаю 2 скрипта, запускаю так node *.js. Через постман отправляю запрос, все норм если не закрыть канал, но если я его закрываю то получаю ошибку, не смог найти примера node + rabbit, как правильно надо делать

Comment: @Total Pusher я не могу понять как правильно его закрывать и где

Comment: Почему 2 скрипта, а не один? `node *.js` - такой вариант допустим, но это значит, что сначала запустится первый скрипт, а затем второй. Я не понимаю, зачем так делать? Вообще правильно - запускать через `npm run start`, но для этого нужно кое-что настроить, подробности в уроке должны быть.

Comment: Скрипт работает в режиме сервера, то есть постоянно? Тогда соединение закрывать не нужно. А нужно корректно обрабатывать случай, когда соединение с кроликом пропало.

Comment: @TotalPusher да скрипты работают постоянно, просто в примерах на ютубе, и вообще в поиске, я везде встречаю закрытие канала, только на странице либы amqplib, у него в описании закрытие канала или соединения. я только начал изучать rabbit, раньше пробовал все на exspress. Есть сайт spa на express, вот я и решил попробовать переделать его с монолита на микросервисы, и это меня привело к rabbitmq

Comment: @TotalPusher без закрытия соединения эти скрипты работаю без ошибок, и сообщения доставляются, но в примерах я встречаю закрытие канала, вот меня и привело на мысль, надо ли закрывать канал или соединение rabbita

Comment: Закрыли соединение - больше от кролика не получите сообщений. И не отправите. Зачем так делается в примерах, не видя их, трудно сказать. Если примеры для PHP, то PHP работает в режиме подключился - отработал запрос - отключился, и так со всеми - базой, кроликом, остальным. Это дизайн пыха такой. Для ноды в режиме демона правильно держать соединение открытым и реагировать, если оно пропало. Как? В мане к библиотеке написано. Вот `on("connect")` срабатывает при подключении. Я не помню, но вроде там есть еще события типа disconnect, error - вот их нужно обрабатывать

Comment: @TotalPusher да на node, и если дисконект, то как можно переподключить его автоматически? Просто в примере на сайте кролика для node js показано 
в моем вопросе в самом верху connection.close();
    process.exit(0) https://rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-javascript.html

Comment: @TotalPusher вот и у меня возник вопрос, зачем там так сделано, или это просто пример, но так делать не обязательно?

Comment: @TotalPusher В мане к библиотеке написано, ссылку пожалуйста на это

Comment: `process.exit(0)` грохает текущий скрипт, соединение с кроликом закрывается (даже если это явно не делать), скрипт перестает слушать порт, так как завершается. В примере по ссылке скрипт отправляет и получает сообщение. Затем он завершает свое выполнение. На этом все. А вы добавили строку `app.listen(3009, () => {` которая на самом деле превращает ваш скрипт в демон, который НЕ завершается сам, а слушает порт. И разывать соединение в этом случае не нужно. А нужно, наоборот, стараться поддерживать все открытым, чтобы логика продолжала работать.

Comment: @TotalPusher Спасибо